# Migrated from jdk 8 to 11, got empty String where was normal String before

Tags: java

After migration my project to jdk 11 my method

```
public static double getNumber(String s, int position) {
    String a = s.replaceAll("[A-Za-zА-Яа-я;()·.\\-]", "").trim().replaceAll(",", ".");
    String numberString = (a.split(" ")[position]);
    return Double.parseDouble(numberString);
}
```

that was made to get number from specific position in a line with words and several numbers (bla bla bla 12,4 25,2 1,7 for example), and was working perfectly on jdk 8 suddenly stopped working. I got this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty
>   String    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543)  at
>   CheckDownloadEdit.Util.PdfsUtil.getNumber(PdfsUtil.java:71)

Nothing else was changed. If I switch back to jdk 8 it works perfectly fine. It is the first time I see such sudden and not obvious mistake after upgrading.
I need help with understanding what could cause it and how to fix it.

Comment: It feels like your input data changed, not the code.  Would be helpful to see the line of input that caused the error.

Comment: Please share the exact input `String s` and `position` that you're testing for. I could confirm with Java 11 that the input string `"12,4 25,2 1,7"` and position `1` works just fine

Comment: exact line is 
 Октябрь 38333 108,3 100,8 105,4 100,6 
and position is 2
Also, when I tried with jdk 11 and tried to find at what moment its all breaks down println command gave me empty line instead of mentioned above. "" and thats all.

Comment: I get `105.4` as the result of the previous input you've shared. You should share the code that's calling this method as well, seems like there could be something there mostly.

Comment: Uhhh guys sorry looks like its was my fault and also the fault of (Month month = Month.of(number);) that was used in some previous methods to search specific line in the document (thats why it has October (Октябрь) in it. In jdk 8 system name of month is October and in jdk 11 its october. Because of that small letter at the beginning it couldnt find that line and my program broke